# Vue JS CSS style binding

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to bind CSS styling to vuejs tags. I dont seem to be able to get it working.
Below is the code which i am trying. Can anyone help me out with this? I am not able to get the Styling to work. I am trying this as well as binding based on conditional. Both doesnt seem to work. Can anyone help me with this? I have tried all the ways i could find on stackoverflow, none of them seem to work for me. Can any one help me if i am doing something wrong?

```
  <b-table
      class="PatientTable"
      borderless
      hover
      v-on:row-clicked="redirectToPatientView"
      :items="users"
      :fields="fields"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :per-page="perPage"
      id="tableData"
    >
      <template v-for="key1 in fields" v-slot:[`cell(${key1})`]="{ value }" id="tableData"  >
        
       <b class="patientData" id="tableData" v-bind:key="key1" v-bind:style="'{font-size:200px;}'">{{ value }}</b>
      </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:class` binding instead?

```html
<component :class="{'your-classname' : condition}">
```

Since inline styling is not really advisable. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a style, pass in an object instead of a string of an object.

```
<!-- Instead of: -->
<b :style="'{font-size:200px;}'">{{ value }}</b>

<!-- Do: -->
<b :style="{ 'font-size' : '200px' }">{{ value }}</b>
```

Notice that, in the second line, the object is placed directly into the double-quotes, without its own set of single-quotes. The contents of those double-quotes are straight up JavaScript, so you don't have to escape the object in them. What you're essentially trying to do is along these lines:

```
<b :style="styleBinding">{{ value }}</b>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      styleBinding: {
        'font-size': '200px',
        'margin-top': '5em',
        'other-css-property': 'value'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It's just that, since you're only using a single property, it's a little cleaner to do in-line in the template.